# Correct way to consume 3rd party API with query in Django + React (Backend + Frontend)

Tags: reactjs, django, api, rest, openweathermap

I'm using Django on my backend and React on my frontend. I want to consume the OpenWeatherMap API. For security reasons, I want to keep my API key on the backend. Currently, I have this working on my Django app. When a POST request is made, the Django view renders the information required from OpenWeatherMap. How can the user type the query in React, send the query to to the backend and get the results on the frontend?

I have a very hacky way of doing this currently:

1. I POST (using axios) the city that the user enters in React to a REST API that I built in Django.
2. The backend queries the OpenWeatherMap API with the city that the user enters and POSTs the data that it gets from OpenWeatherMaps back to my API.
3. After this, the frontend uses a GET request on my API to show the information to the user.

I'm pretty sure this isn't the correct way to do this but I couldn't find any other questions on this, and I'm pretty new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

First two steps are just fine. Instead of step 3. return the response from OpenWeather as a response to POST request from step 1. and resolve it in your React code.

On the second thought and to be fine with REST guidelines:

1. use GET to call your API with user's provided city name (POST is usually called to create a new resource - it's just a convention)
2. inside your API call OpenWeatherMap API with the city name
3. return the result to your React app as a response to GET from point 1.

More on REST API guidelines: https://restfulapi.net/

Comment: How can I add my city name to the GET request in React? The reason I used POST is so that I can add the city name as data to send to the backend, where the OpenWeatherMap API can be queried with the city name.

Comment: according to REST API guidelines your API should accept something like this: https://myapidomain.com/cities/[city_name] but to achieve this you must play a little with .htaccess file on your server side to parse API request accordingly. The other way is to form URI in React like this: https://myapidomain.com/?cityName=[city_name] and then read cityName in your Django backend

Comment: If I have a POST function in Django that carries out some operations, how can I trigger that through my react frontend?

Comment: you mean - how to get the response from your API back to React front-end?

Comment: Kind of. I have a function in Django that checks if a POST request is made (however this only checks if a POST request is made from the Django app since they are linked). So while I can use my local API as a vessel to send the city name to the backend, and send the data back to the frontend, the Django function that adds the data back to the local API after querying OpenWeatherMaps will never be triggered unless a POST request is made from the backend. Therefore, the data will not be added to my local API without a POST request from the backend. That is part of the architecture confusing me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django but can you make like `axios.get` in React frontend to your django backend and intercept it?